# how can I make a python dictionary from excel file using openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, dictionary, openpyxl

simply I have 2 columns in excel file . lets say A and B
after reading the excel file I want to store the values in dictionary like this :
{A1:B1, A2:B2,.....} until the end of columns contents. How can I do that.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `{"A1": value_in_A1, "A2": value_in_A2, ..., "B1": value_in_B1, ...}`?

Comment: I think yes .for example I have some data like this :

 brand  Ford
model Mustang
year        1964

I want to be in this form:



thisdict = {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": 1964
}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote demo code as below, hope is helps.

```
import openpyxl
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('./test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.active

dictionary = {}

for row in range(1, worksheet.max_row + 1):
  key = worksheet.cell(row, 1).value
  value = worksheet.cell(row, 2).value
  dictionary[key] = value

print(dictionary)
```

Comment: it is. thank you